# How to change programming layout after setting it at the first execution?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, layout

When starting Visual Studio 2008 you are asked to choose a programming layout (preset?), which can be C++ or C# (or generic?). Few months ago I choose the C++ preset because I was working on a C++ project, while now I'm working to a C# project. Is there a way to reset the Visual Studio layout to C#?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Go to:

1. *Tools > Import and Export Settings*
2. *Import selected environment settings*
3. *Yes, save my current settings* (if you want to backup current settings; *No*, if you don't want to)
4. Choose one of the following under *Default Settings*:

   - General
   - JavaScript
   - Visual Basic
   - Visual C#
   - Visual C++
   - Web Development
   - Web Development (Code Only)

## Notes

- Alternatively, in step 2, you may choose *Reset all settings*.
- You may also use [`/ResetSettings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx) command line switch.

Comment: Works for Visual Studio 2019 too!

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio 2015 it's the same steps described by @Dariusz Woźniak but you can select "Reset all settings" instead of "Import" on step 2.